# ng-class evaluates to wrong classname

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

In my angular app I have some HTML with angulars `ng-class` directive:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{true:'btn-success', false:'btn-danger'}[status.isSoftware()]">
    <span>{{status.isSoftware()}}</span>
</button>
```

This evaluates to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{true:'btn-success', false:'btn-danger'}[status.isSoftware()]">
    <span>false</span>
</button>
```

As you can see, `ng-class` evaluates the expression to `true` and assigns `.btn-success` to my button while the `span` evaluates the same expression to `false` (what is the expexted behaviour). I debugged the function and it always returns `false` (as it should).

How is this even possible? I have quite similar statements throughout my application and everywhere else it works fine.

Someone has any idea? What am I missing here? What could cause the problem?

EDIT (reduced code sample):

```
angular.module("abc", [])
.factory("StatusService", [
"APP_MODEL",
    function (APP_MODEL) {

        var m_Model = {
                Software : false,
                Locked   : false
            },

            m_Status = {
                isSoftware  : function () {
                    return m_Model.Software && !m_Model.Locked;
                },
                isHardware  : function () {
                    return !m_Model.Software && !m_Model.Locked;
                },
                isLocked    : function () {
                    return m_Model.Locked;
                }
            },

            listenToServerUpdates = function () {
                //
                APP_MODEL.Software.addServerUpdateCallback(function (value) {
                    m_Model.Software = value == 1;
                });

                //
                APP_MODEL.Locked.addServerUpdateCallback(function (value) {
                    m_Model.Locked = value == 1;
                });
            };

        listenToServerUpdates();

        return {
            status : m_Status
        };
    }
])
.controller("ABCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    "StatusService",
    function ($scope, service) {
        $scope.status = service.status;
    }
]);
```

Comment: Can you post `status.isSoftware` function?

Comment: I made a small fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nf2fwmes/ and can not replicate your behavior. Can you add some more details? The status.isSoftware function would be very interesting to see.

Comment: I added some code. I get values from a server. In my case software is "1" and Locked is "1". So isSoftware() should evaluate to false (as it does in the span)...

Comment: btw: Using a ng-disabled with the same expression works just fine...

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), you should use `ng-class` in the following matter.

Instead of:

```
ng-class="{true:'btn-success', false:'btn-danger'}[status.isSoftware()]"
```

You should use:

```
ng-class="{'btn-success' : status.isSoftware(), 'btn-danger': !status.isSoftware()}"
```

**EDIT**: However, I am not sure if using a function call will work. Therefore I *would* recommend using a property instead of a function call.

**EDIT 2**: Apparently it works. Thanks for all the input from the comments.

Comment: Hm. Using your syntax works for me. That's interesting as I saw the syntax used by me here on SO and used it on many places in my app (with and without function calls) and everything worked fine...

Comment: @adt: I used your fiddle to reproduce my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/nf2fwmes/2/

Comment: I'm sorry!! I had a syntax error while using your approach so my expression evaluated to false (as expected). After correcting this it gives me a true in ng-class again, like before. So the issue has NOT been solved with this answer. I guess the error is not by syntax then...

Comment: btw: I tried to use properties instead of functions but it does not work neither with mine nor your syntax.

Comment: The jsfiddles provided by you and by @adt work for me - the button changes colour as intended. Could you provide your solution which does *not* work in order for us to fix it? Because I currently do not see any issues.

Comment: `ngClass` can be used in several different ways. It doesn't mean one is better than the other; it depends on the usecase.